How to have the tilda be closer to the number?
How do you have the tilda be closer to the number, or to eliminate the space between the tilda and the number?
Even without a space between the tilda and the 1, it seems this command creates a space in the resulting output screenshot.
($\sim1s$) 


Use braces {\sim}. But if the s stands for second then it should be written upright.
